# Wordpress Custom Logo

Tags: wordpress

I'm pretty new about coding, and i'm trying to build a Wordpress custom theme.
I'm stacked on the logo section and I really can't understand what i'm doing wrong:

```
<?php if ( get_theme_mod('apc_logo_image', '') != '' ): ?>
        <img class="animate" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png" alt="logo sito">
    <?php elseif ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
        <img class="animate" src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'apc_logo_image', '' ); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'apc_logo_alt_text', '' ); ?>">
    <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I would like to do the follow:
If I upload an images from Customizer, than it would be visible as logo.
If don't and i have a logo in a specific path like: /assets/logo ecc... than it should be visible like logo.
if don't, then I would like to see the name of the website as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So working code:

```
 <?php 
  $logoFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/' . wp_get_theme()->get('TextDomain') . '/assets/images/logo/logo.png';
  if ( (bool)get_theme_mod('apc_logo_image')) : ?>
     <img class="animate" src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'apc_logo_image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'apc_logo_alt_text'); ?>"> 
     <?php else : ?> 
        <?php if ( file_exists($logoFile) ) : ?> 
        <img class="animate" src="<?php echo '/wp-content/themes/' . wp_get_theme()->get('TextDomain') . '/assets/images/logo/logo.png'?>" alt="logo sito"> 
        <?php else : ?> 
        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1> 
        <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Update answer try now))

Comment: Now, customizer is not loading image and path is still not found

Comment: Can you screen what way you create customizer setting & control? 
If this a customizer WP_Customize_Image_Control?
Or it is just custom logo field?
And try updated code))

Comment: `/* Logo Image */
    $wp_customize ->add_setting( 'apc_logo_image', array( 'default' => '' ) );
    $wp_customize ->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control( $wp_customize, 'apc_logo_image', array(
      'section' => 'apc_logo',
      'label' => __( 'Logo Image', 'apc' ),
      'settings' => 'apc_logo_image'
    )));`

Comment: Ok. And i have many codes with this, and i get banner img SRC for ex.:
<?php echo get_theme_mod('modica_banner_img');?>
So lets try updated second part of code in my answer)

Comment: There was error in path /asseta/ must be /assets/ i think))

Comment: Ok, now path is working and customizer the same.
If i don't load image with customizer and don't put a logo in that path, Name of theme is not showing correctly

Comment: bloginfo( 'name' ) Displays the “Site Title” set in Settings > General in admin area
If you need theme name - wp_get_theme()->get('TextDomain'); or wp_get_theme()->get('Name');

Comment: I see a kind of error image and a test saying: logo sito (this is a alt attribute i think)

Comment: Img alt attribute may be any string... it's not error. Copy error message here.
Error may bu this: get_template_directory_uri
- its return parent theme url, if you use child theme there will be error

Comment: If your theme child try get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead of get_template_directory_uri()

Comment: I'm not using a child theme, error seems to be: GET http://apc.local/wp-content/themes/apc/assets/images/logo/logo.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: could be ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) the problem?

Comment: No, problem with returned path, there must not be apc.local
Try insert to img src='/wp-content/themes/apc/assets/images/logo/logo.png'
if working - say me)

Comment: GET http://apc.local/wp-content/themes/apc/wp-content/themes/apc/assets/images/logo/logo.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: it's like is searching for path even if we set up to show name of theme

Comment: <img class="animate" src="/wp-content/themes/apc/assets/images/logo/logo.png" alt="logo sito"> This way not working?

Comment: Nope same error:
GET http://apc.local/wp-content/themes/apc/assets/images/logo/logo.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Then, check if there realy is logo.PNG in folder /wp-content/themes/apc/assets/images/logo/

Comment: Oh wait, if logo.png is in a folder everything is working.
But if I don't have a logo in a folder, how can i show just a name of the theme?

Comment: This is why I thought ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) was wrong.

Comment: Added string logo path to variable
`$logoFile = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/logo/logo.png';`
And instead of check homepage set:
`if (file_exists($logoFile)) {...` condition

Comment: Tried and Path is not found logo.png.

Comment: This also changed like so?
`<img class="animate" src="<?php echo $logoFile;?>" alt="logo sito">`

Comment: Yes I confirm, still no path found

Comment: Change finding the file to this:
`$logoFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/assets/images/logo/logo.png';`
Code updated

Comment: Nothing to do, I’m trying to change a little thing, but it is not finding any path logo.png

Comment: And finaly last Updated Code
This works:
`$logoFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/' . wp_get_theme()->get('TextDomain') . '/assets/images/logo/logo.png';`

Comment: I'm so sorry,
GET http://apc.local/Users/anpace/Local%20Sites/apc/app/public/wp-content/themes/apc/assets/images/logo/logo.png 404 (Not Found)
same erro as before

Comment: Something is wrong. Usualy 404 because there no logo.png
But where you get this error?
In what string?

Comment: So try this:
`$logoFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/' . wp_get_theme()->get('TextDomain') . '/assets/images/logo/logo.png';
var_dump(file_exists($logoFile));`

Comment: And say me what will print var_dump

Comment: And lets change img tag to this:
 
`<img class="animate" src="<?php echo '/wp-content/themes/' . wp_get_theme()->get('TextDomain') . '/assets/images/logo/logo.png'?>" alt="logo sito">`

Comment: I see this message on screen:
Users/anpace/Local Sites/apc/app/public/wp-content/themes/apc/template-parts/header/site-branding.php:12:boolean true

Comment: boolean true means that logo.png exist, there uploaded logo.png now?

Comment: Nope, still no found

Comment: <?php 
  $logoFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/' . wp_get_theme()->get('TextDomain') . '/assets/images/logo/logo.png'; var_dump(file_exists($logoFile));
  if ( (bool)get_theme_mod( 'apc_logo_image' )) : ?>
     <img class="animate" src="<?php echo '/wp-content/themes/' . wp_get_theme()->get('TextDomain') . '/assets/images/logo/logo.png'?>" alt="logo sito">

Comment: <?php else : ?> 
        <?php if ( file_exists($logoFile) ) : ?> 
        <img class="animate" src="<?php echo $logoFile;?>" alt="logo sito"> 
        <?php else : ?> 
         <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1> 
        <?php endif; ?> 
    <?php endif ?>

Comment: You have old code
Please look my updated answer in the total top)))) 
http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2021/08/15/0024/4040/1621960/60/2e2b5689f3.jpg

Comment: Finally seems work very well. what was the problem ?
I see you have a agency, are you work alone or you have a group of people are you working with?

Comment: Problem was in the first condition)) I told about img tag in the deep, and you chage first one))) I'm working alone as freelancer)

Comment: So if working, dont forget check the answer as correct please))